# Creating a function with PYTZ's timezones

Tags: python, python-3.x, timezone, pytz

I'm trying to make a function called to_timezone that
will take a timezone name as a string, and then convert 'starter'
to that timezone, using pytz's timezones...I want it to return a a new datetime.

I want it to be whatever timezone that comes in as 'tz'.
I don't want to hardcode the 'pytz timezone object'
How would I accomplish this?
Here is my code:

```
import datetime

import pytz

starter = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 21, 23, 29))

def to_timezone(tz):
    tz_utc = pytz.timezone('#pytz timezone object')
    starter = tz_utc.astimezone
    return starter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `tz` is a timezone name from the tz database such as `"America/New_York"` then you could pass it directly to `pytz.timezone` and use `astimezone()`, `normalize()` methods to convert an aware datetime object `starter` to `tz` timezone:

```
def to_timezone(aware_dt, zonename):
    tz = pytz.timezone(zonename)
    return tz.normalize(aware_dt.astimezone(tz))
```

Example:

```
starter = datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 21, 23, 29, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
print(to_timezone(starter, "America/Los_Angeles"))
# -> 2015-10-21 16:29:00-07:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can just pass whatever comes in as `tz` to `pytz.timezone`:

```
def to_timezone(tz):
    tz_utc = pytz.timezone(tz)
```

So you could for example call `to_timezone('Europe/London')`.